# Need T-SQL code to show the records if first row value doesn't match with last row value within each group

Tags: sql-server

I have one table with 4 columns, say Rec_Id, as int, Name  as varchar, ID1 as int, ID2 as int datatypes.

**Create table:**

```
Create table Sample
 (
  Rec_Id Int Not null,
  Name varchar(30) null,
  ID1 int null,
  ID2 int null,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sample] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
  [Rec_Id] ASC
 )
```

**Insert Statement:**

```
Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 1 ,'A',1,2)
  Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 2 ,'A', 2,3)
  Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 3 ,'A', 3 ,1)

 Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 4 ,'B', 1 , 2)
 Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values (  5 , 'B',  2 , 3)
 Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values (  6 , 'B' , 3 , null)

 Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 7 ,'C', 1 , 2)
  Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 8 ,'C' , 2 , 3)
  Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 9 ,'C' , 3 , 4)
  Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values (10 ,'C' , 5 , 1 ) 

Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 11 ,'D', 2 , 3)
 Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 12 , 'D', 3 , 4)
 Insert into sample (Rec_ID,Name,ID1,ID2) values ( 13 , 'D' , 4 , 3)
```

My source data looks like this..

```
Rec_Id Name     ID1   ID2
   1    A        1     2        
   2    A        2     3
   3    A        3     1

   4    B        1     2
   5    B        2     3
   6    B        3    null    --> Need to display this row in the output, because 1 is missing in ID2

   7    C        1     2
   8    C        2     3
   9    C        3     4
  10    C        5     1      --> Need to display this row in the output, because 4 is missing after 3 in ID1

  11    D        2     3
  12    D        3     4
  13    D        4     3    --> Need to display this row in the output, because 2 is missing in ID2
```

**My Output should look like below:**

```
Rec_Id  Name    ID1    ID2
 6       B       3     
10       C       5      1
13       D       4      3
```

ok, let me explain in other words...In the above example right now 'Name' column has 4 groups, Name =A, B, C ,D.

A group- has 3 records which make one loop. I am saying it formed one loop becoz 3rd row value in ID2 column(ID2=1) matches with 1st row ID1 column(ID1=1).
 Same loop concept implies for B , C and D groups.

--A - group records:

```
Name   ID1   ID2
  A     1     2
  A     2     3
  A     3     1
```

--B - group records:

```
Name  ID1   ID2
  B    1     2
  B    2     3
  B    3    null
```

B group - has 3 records which is broken loop. I am saying it is broken loop becoz 3rd row value in ID2 column(ID2=null) doesn't matches with 1st row ID1 column(ID1=1).

C- group records: Same loop concept implies for C group. If there is a break in the series need to display.

D- group records:

```
Name     ID1   ID2
  D       2     3
  D       3     4  
  D       4     3
```

D group - has 3 records which is broken loop. I am saying it is broken loop becoz 3rd row value in ID2 column(ID2=3) doesn't matches with 1st row ID1 column(ID1=2).

So, I need t-sql to get above output.

Thanks in advance,
 RH

Comment: Which SQL server version?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012 version.

Comment: Hm... if id_a has the sequence 2,3,4 and id_b has the sequence 3,4,5, which row is wrong?

Comment: Joachim, The 3rd row is wrong.Id_b has to be in this sequence 3,4,2 instead of 3,4,5

Comment: @user3524482 So id_a 3,4,2 and id_b 4,5,3 means the 3:rd row is still wrong since id_a needs to be 3,4,5?

Comment: yes. your are correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to answer your question. You may want to break it up some depending on your business rules. Based on your sample I could see that the sum of ID1 column equals sum of ID2 column. The rules depend on the first and last values in the ID columns so I figured those out too (used MIN and MAX to get those and add to each row so I could filter at the end).

```
WITH errs AS (
SELECT s.Rec_id, s.[Name], s.ID1, s.ID2, p.startId, p.lastId, p.TotID1, p.TotID2, 0 AS artificialID
FROM Sample AS s
INNER JOIN (
        -- general filter for which groups have problems, assumes sum of ID1 column equals sum of ID2 column (optimize query in case this is bigger data set)
        SELECT s0.[Name], SUM(ISNULL(s0.ID1,0)) AS TotID1, SUM(ISNULL(s0.ID2,0)) AS TotID2
            , MIN(s0.ID1) AS startId
            , MAX(s0.ID1) AS lastId
        FROM Sample AS s0
        GROUP BY s0.[Name]
        HAVING SUM(ISNULL(s0.ID1,0)) <> SUM(ISNULL(s0.ID2,0))) AS p ON s.[Name] = p.[Name]
),
-- get a list of those with a missing row when the last row in the group exists and has the right ID2 value
er1 AS (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT e.Rec_id, e.[Name], e.ID1, e.ID2, e.startId, e.lastId, e.totID1, e.TotID2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.[Name] ORDER BY e.ID1) AS artificialID
FROM errs AS e 
WHERE e.[Name] NOT IN (SELECT o.[Name] FROM errs AS o WHERE (ISNULL(o.ID1,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(o.ID2,0) = 0)) 
) AS er1a
  WHERE er1a.ID1 <> er1a.artificialID
                       -- get a list of those where the last row exists and ID2 is correct, IE, something missing in the middle
    AND er1a.[Name] IN (SELECT o1.[Name] FROM errs AS o1 WHERE (ISNULL(o1.ID1,0) = lastId AND ISNULL(o1.ID2,0) = o1.startId))
)

SELECT e.*
FROM errs AS e 
WHERE (ISNULL(e.ID1,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(e.ID2,0) = 0)
UNION 
SELECT e1.*
FROM er1 AS e1 
UNION 
-- the third group - where the last row does not have the right ID2 on it
SELECT e2.*
FROM errs AS e2
WHERE (ISNULL(e2.ID1,0) = lastId AND ISNULL(e2.ID2,0) <> e2.startId)
ORDER BY [Name],ID1, ID2
```

Comment: Please remember to click answered if this solved your question.